# How to define compiler flags specifically for object or shared object files with CMake?

Tags: cmake

How can I define a compile flag only for the command which produces the object file or only for the command which produces the shared object/executable file?

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_source_files_properties.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/COMPILE_FLAGS.html

Comment: target_compile_options is not available for my CMake version. COMPILE_FLAGS for the target does add the flags to the object files as well. Now I am trying LINK_FLAGS.